# How can i achieve this kind of corner redius with shadow view iOS swift?

Tags: swift, uiview

I am trying to make a design which have top left corner radius and bottom right corner radius with shadow. I am able to make shadow also corner radius around the view.But when i am trying to give corner radius only to side shadow or radius is not showing. Hare what i have done

```
 extension UIview {
   //corner radius function
       func roundCornersForView(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                    byRoundingCorners: corners,
                                    cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
            let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            maskLayer.frame = self.bounds
            maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
            self.layer.mask = maskLayer
        }
    }


    func setShadow(){
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        // set the shadow properties
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.0)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
        self.roundCornersForView(corners: [.topLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 20)

    }



}

 /// finally call it table cell


  cell?.BackView.setShadow()
```

[here is the design what i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sOzy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Why write a separate function to draw rect and then apply cornerRadius mask to your view? Replace the function's contents with:

```
yourView.layer.masksToBounds = true
yourView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
yourView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
```

2) Once you mask your view's corners and set its `masksToBounds` property to `true`, you can set shadow to the view's layer and it will automatically wrap around the rounded corners as you desire:-

```
yourView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: -0.5)
yourView.layer.shadowRadius = 1
yourView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red:0.01, green:0.05, blue:0.09, alpha:0.18).cgColor
yourView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
```

3) It's advised to play with your cell's UI attributes(a subview's cornerRadius and shadow in your case) in the cell class's `awakeFromNib()` or an `init()` method rather than in your delegate methods as they get called a lot of times and hence **break the whole point of reusability**

Have tested the code to apply shadow and it works fine for me. Hope this helps!